# PHP codes don't work in .asp files

Tags: php, iis, asp-classic

I have got a IIS Server on Windows Server 2008 R2.
I have a index.asp file and I want to put php codes in it.
This asp files only have php codes.
Can't work .php codes in asp.
http://prntscr.com/7axmit like this.

Comment: That's exactly it: PHP codes don't work in .asp files.

Comment: If it's a php file it needs a .php extension, and as Frank says you need to install php on your server

Answer (score 2):

Php and ASP are different technologies and cannot be mixed.  Classic asp will work with VbSCript, Jscript, Python and Perl, but not php.

If you want to use PHP code on a windows IIS server then you need to install PHP into the web server.

Comment: Practically speaking we can forget about Perlscript and Python now.  Support for them wasn't provided by Microsoft, it came with the ActiveState distributions of those languages, and I think ActiveState have dropped it from their most recent versions.  They certainly have with Python.